# Does Google Log Data when using Google Charting API

Tags: google-visualization

I am thinking of using Google Charting API for a visualization app.. But the Client Data is sensitive and hence I want to ensure that Data Does not get stored on Google servers when I send the data via the HTTP request..

Would appreciate if you can be elaborate about the terms..

Also, let me know if it is advisable to use Google Charting API?

Comment: If you're using HTTP and not something secured, Google storing the data is the least of your worries...

Comment: The App will be on an Intranet within the organization... So that's not I am worried about..

Comment: All I am concerned is will Google Store my data?

Comment: Not that. When you send the data to Google via HTTP, you run over the public internet. Then, it's really easy to intercept. Just use a script or something to generate your charts instead.

Answer (score 2):

Most charts do not send any data to Google's servers.  See the "Data Policy" section of each chart you are considering using for details (example: [Timeline Charts Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Data_Policy)).